# navigationTitle too long in swiftui

Tags: ios, swiftui, uinavigationbar

Is there any way to make the navigationTitle at the top to be a multiline one, or shrink when that is too long? Now, in my case, it shows "..." at the end because of not enough spaces to display. i have checked all other posts and none of the results are related to swiftui solution.

Comment: Can you show any code? Would it be sufficient if you just did `.navigationBarTitle(Text("An extremely long navbar title to showcase this").        .lineLimit(1).minimumScaleFactor(0.5))`?

Comment: @RickardElimää your option does not work

Answer (score 3):

```
init() {
    UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
}
```

you can add this into your view struct

Reference to this [SwiftUI Size to fit or word-wrap navigation title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69325928/swiftui-size-to-fit-or-word-wrap-navigation-title)