# SwiftUI Size to fit or word-wrap navigation title

Tags: swiftui, uinavigationbar

I have a navigation title that is too large on some smaller devices.
I've read many ways to set the `titleTextAttributes` and `largeTitleTextAttributes` of the `UINavigationBar.appearance()` however when setting the paragraph style to word wrap, it seems to remove the standard `...` clipping and have the text continue off the edge of the screen without wrapping:

```
init() {
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [
        .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
    ]
}
```

I want to maintain the SwiftUI behaviour where the title is shown as large text until the view is scrolled up and it moves to the navigation bar, so getting the `.toolbar` directly won't help.

I also don't want to just specify a smaller font as I only want it to shrink or wrap if necessary.

Has anyone managed to achieve this?

Comment: The solution ended up being quite simple https://stackoverflow.com/a/68428803/1077601

Comment: It would be helpful if you could also include where in your SwiftUI project you actually used this solution. It's not self-evident from the post you linked to where one would put that code.

Comment: You can put it in an init of the view or even in the App Delegate.

Answer (score 6):

You can add this line on the initializer of the view where yo have the issue

```
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Example:

```
struct YourView: View {
    init() {
        UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Your content")
                .navigationBarTitle("Very very large title to fit in screen")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on Jose's answer, if you want to apply this to all navigation titles throughout your app, place the line in the init of your App struct:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    init() {
        UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    }
}
```